# BIND DNS Forwarder Performance

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Does anyone know how to measure the performance of forwarders that are configured on a BIND DNS (may be in terms of RTT, SRTT)?

This will help to know which forwarders are working optimally, I tend to script this so as to get a trend over a particular period of time.

Answer (score 2):

BIND uses SRTT as a variable to decide which DNS to use, so you can get access to it dumping the cache with the command `rndc dumpdb` will dump the cache in bind's directory (or the directory specified by the `dump-file` configuration directive).

In that file `named_dump.db` you will be able to get the SRTT of each nameserver, just grep the file for `srttp` and you will find the interesting lines, then filter with the IPs of the forwarders you want to look at.

Comment: Many thanks Pablo.... Below is the output from one of the DNS servers: ;       83.1xx.8.2xx [srtt 28209] [flags 00002000] [ttl -16542]
;       83.1xx.8.2xx [srtt 28209] [flags 00002000] [ttl -16542]
;       8.8.8.8 [srtt 0] [flags 00000000] [ttl 224] ....... Any idea about the negative TTL value? Also is srtt 0 for 8.8.8.8 make sense?